# ZipFile.infolist() return wrong ordering than actual zipfile ordering. Any workaround suggest?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to get files inside zipfile and renaming them from 1 to n when extarcting. But when the actual filenames also start from 1 to n ZipFile.infolist() return wrong ordering.

This is how I trying to get result:

```
with ZipFile(file) as zf:
        for i, file in enumerate(zf.infolist(), 1):
            file.filename = f'{i}.{file.filename.split(".")[-1]}'
            zf.extract(file, file_path)
```

And this is how the actual files ordering look like:
[image]

When I debug to code process ZipFile.infolist() return a list containing a ZipInfo objects like this:
[image]

As you can see from the images, actual ordering is like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...n. But ZipFile.infolist() return it like 1,10,11,11,12,13...n

Am I doing it wrong? Or is there any workaround? I think in the worst case I should name actual file names in zipfile from 01, 02, 03, 04 to n. But this is unreliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program you are using to display the contents of your zip file is sorting the filenames numerically before it displays them to you. The extraction with python is done in the order they are stored in the zip file.

Here is a worked example that shows the issue.

First create some files

```bash
$ touch 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg  7.jpg 8.jpg 10.jpg 21.jpg 100.jp
g 205.jpg
```

Add them to a zip file in a random order

````
$ zip test.zip 10.jpg 2.jpg 1.jpg 100.jpg 21.jpg 8.jpg 205.jpg 7.
jpg 3.jpg 
  adding: 10.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 2.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 1.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 100.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 21.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 8.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 205.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 7.jpg (stored 0%)
  adding: 3.jpg (stored 0%)```
````

Check what `unzip` thinks is in the file

```
$ unzip -l test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   10.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   2.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   1.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   100.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   21.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   8.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   205.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   7.jpg
        0  2023-10-01 15:44   3.jpg
---------                     -------
        0                     9 files
```

It displays them in the order they were added.

Now print contents with python

```py
import zipfile

zipfilename = "test.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename) as zf:
        for file in zf.namelist():
            print(file)
```

the code outputs this

```
$ python try.py 
10.jpg
2.jpg
1.jpg
100.jpg
21.jpg
8.jpg
205.jpg
7.jpg
3.jpg
```

That matches the file insertion order

You can work around this by sorting the contents of the zip file yourself. The key points about your files are

- the filenames are numbers
- you want to ignore the filename extension, `jpg`, in the sort.
- you need the filename sorted numerically rather than in dictionary order.

The python code can use the `sorted` function to sort the file by filename

```py
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

print()
zipfilename = "test1.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename) as zf:
        for file in sorted(zf.namelist(), key=lambda x: int(Path(x).stem)):
            print(file)
```

this outputs the files in order

```
$ python try.py 

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
10.jpg
21.jpg
100.jpg
205.jpg
```

Let's unpick the line with the `sorted` function

```py
for file in sorted(zf.namelist(), key=lambda x: int(Path(x).stem)):
```

The `sorted` function is given two parameters:

1. the list of filenames to sort via `zf.namelist()`
2. a function that works out the key to be used in sorting, `lambda x: int(Path(x).stem)`.

   The call to `Path(x).stem` takes  full filename (e.g. `205.jpg`) and returns the filename without the extension (e.g. `205`).

   The `int` converts the string `205` into the integer value `205`. That value is then returned to `sorted` and allows the filenames to be sorted *numerically*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the problem is a bit more nuanced. The issue is that the program that initially makes the zip file may add them to the file name-sorted order rather than the order that the files were made, not that they are being listed with a sort. This means they will be inserted in the zip file in the wrong order. And a simple sort by name won't work.

In my situation, my contact elsewhere has a folder with 13,653 images. These were all scanned in order, front the back. Order is important to make sure we get the back of each page with the proper front. I did not name them, so we are stuck with the format. These were all added to the zip file on their side.

They have names like this:

```
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_001-00001BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_002-00002BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_003-00003BW200.png
...
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_099-00099BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_100-00100BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_101-00101BW200.png
...
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_999-04938BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_1000-00101BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_1001-00102BW200.png
...
```

I'm using 7zip to display the contents of the zip file, and it provides also a column of the offset into the zip file. If I sort by the offset, then we see:

```
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_001-00001BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_002-00002BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_003-00003BW200.png
...
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_099-00099BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_100-00100BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_1000-00101BW200.png
802a5-26- EV-PA GE-DT_1001-00102BW200.png
...
```

And this is the same order as I find in Zipfile.zipinfo().

So in summary, the files were inserted into the zip file by simple sorted name rather than the order of creation. Of course, if they had named them so the numbers did not overflow the fields, they would have been added in order, but we can't fix that now.

But interestingly, the 7zip program will properly sort these if I click on name column, i.e. after 100 we get 101, 102, 103, rather than 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003

In Python, I find including the length in the sort will usually handle the cases when there are a different number of digits. 7zip must do this sort of sort, which is generally a pretty good idea.

```
# Sort file names first by length, then by name within each length group
sorted_file_names = sorted(file_names, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

This gives me the original order due to this smarter sorting method:

```
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_096-09430BW200.png'] | 94931  |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_097-09431BW200.png'] | 146349 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_098-09432BW200.png'] | 96322  |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_099-09433BW200.png'] | 151022 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_100-09434BW200.png'] | 102428 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_101-09445BW200.png'] | 146831 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_102-09456BW200.png'] | 99936  |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_103-09467BW200.png'] | 154487 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_104-09478BW200.png'] | 110656 |
| ['GENERAL-5-25 BW200/802a5-26-EV-PA GE-DT_105-09489BW200.png'] | 153720 |
```

It turns out this is not exactly the original order, but it at least is well behaved and tends to deal with the mistakes due to the simpler sorting method. I notice here that the range of values in the 95-105 offset are actually other files (that did not have a space after 26- ) but this at least is a reall good way to sort strings that have numbers in them and will tend to get back to reasonable ordering.